# Secure file upload from Node.js server to PHP server

Tags: php, node.js, security, encryption, server

I'm trying to find a safe way to to allow logged in users of my Node.js app `(N)` to upload/delete files *inside their own folder only* on a PHP `(P)` server on a different domain.

Can some expert tell me if the following approach is reasonably secure?

- **N:** On user login, generate a token based on user ID on Node server and salt it with a secret
- Send encrypted token via https to PHP server
- **P:** Decrypt token with known secret and save it in a database table of valid user IDs

-

- **N:** On file upload/delete file request, send file/delete request + encrypted token via https to PHP server
- **P:** Decrypt token with known secret and check if it is in database table of valid user IDs

  - If yes, allow write/delete operation inside folder "userID"
  - If no, send an error message to Node app

My thinking is, that this would work because as the secret we use for salting is only known to Node server and PHP server, anything that gets send over the wire will be of no use to a potential attacker.

Would appreciate if somebody can confirm or point out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs out from the NodeJs application your Php server should delete the users token from database.